# What is the Kubuntu equivalent of `gdebi` that provides a GUI for installing .deb files?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, kde, deb

On Gnome based systems you can install `.deb` files with `gdebi` instead of using the Ubuntu Software Center. What is the equivalent package on KDE using Kubuntu?

Comment: A package `gdebi-kde` exist for Trusty, Xenial and Artful, but unfortunately not for Bionic. In Plasma desktop, `Discover` should do the job. This might be useful: https://userbase.kde.org/Kubuntu/Advanced

Comment: @mook765 - Discover doesn't tell you what dependencies are to be installed (unlike gdebi).

Comment: You can use gdebi on Kubuntu, but not by means of the default Plasma file manager, called "Dolphin".

If you open your Downloads folder in a different file manager, such as "Nautilus", you can install .deb files through gdebi.

It is not recommended to set Nautilus as the default file manager in Kubuntu, but you can still use Nautilus or Thunar as a secondary file manager. (Nautilus has certain other features absent from Dolphin, such as "Open as Administrator" and "Open in Terminal", but that is beyond the scope of this discussion.)

Comment: The solution I offered in my previous comment is less than satisfactory, but there is a fix here that will make gedebi work. Tested on Kubuntu 21.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdebi/+bug/1760910/comments/12. To read the fix in context: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdebi/+bug/1760910

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the tool I was looking for it's called `qapt-deb-installer`

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100044/get-ok-message-when-installing-deb-with-apt-in-terminal-from-context-menu-or-cl and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448677/why-cant-sudo-apt-install-locate-a-deb-file. Apparently, `qapt-deb-installer` doesn't warn you if dependencies are **not satisfied** whereas installing via `apt` does. `apt` seems to be preferred over `dpkg` as well in this context.

Comment: Is there a Kubuntu-compatible installer for .deb packages that will tell you which dependencies were not satisfied? Apt on Kubuntu will tell you there are unsatisfied dependencies, but it doesn't tell you which ones they are.

Comment: @DKBose -   `qapt-deb-installer` does tell *that* dependencies are not satisfied when the case, but doesn't say which ones. But at least it tells which *supplementary* dependencies are to be installed, something which Discover does not.

Answer (score 2):

As a complementary answer in relation to other answers and comments:

- Qapt Package Installer (`qapt-deb-installer`) is *meant* as similar to Gdebi, but, while it tells you when dependencies are missing,  it doesn't list those missing dependencies.

[image]

On the other hand (like Gdebi) it tells you what *supplementary* dependencies are installed when executing a `deb` file.

[image]

Compared to `gdebi`, Discover is similar mostly in that it is able to install from `deb` files (unlike something like Synaptic or its KDE alternatives, Muon and Apper). But when it does, it doesn't tell you if and what dependencies are missing (it simply closes), and, even worse, *it doesn't list the supplementary dependencies before installing them*.

---

I would also suggest an alternative where, while the deb file is installed with `apt` in terminal (`apt` being the program that is run by Gdebi), the action is triggered with a GUI - namely Dolphin file manager - in two possible ways:

~ by associating the deb files with an "application" that would trigger our action, in fact just the `desktop` file `~/.local/share/applications/install-deb-terminal.desktop`, created by us with the form

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=APT in terminal
Comment=Install deb files in terminal with apt
Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f
Icon=/usr/share/icons/breeze/mimetypes/22/application-x-deb.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=System;
```

but that will be seen by the system as a new application that could be associated to the deb file-type

[image]

~ or, by just creating a new context menu in Dolphin for deb files, triggering the same action, with the file `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/install-deb.desktop` of the form

```
[Desktop Entry]

Actions=install
Icon=dialog-information
MimeType=application/vnd.debian.binary-package
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel


[Desktop Action install]
Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f
Icon=/usr/share/icons/breeze/mimetypes/22/application-x-deb.svg
Name=Install with APT in terminal
```

[image]

I guess Dolphin qualifies as a GUI for our purpose. The rest is displayed in terminal - that is: missing dependencies, if the case,

[image]

or supplementary ones that need to be installed:

[image]

But we do not take any action in CLI ourselves, except entering the `sudo` password.

[Thanks to @DKBose I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/q/1100044/925128) where in a question I have presented this solution under a now dead account while I had the same username as now.]