# Get ok message when installing deb with apt in terminal (from context menu or click)

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, scripts

I find `apt` in terminal as the best way to install a program from a deb package. As I prefer it to other gui tools, I want that in the context menu for deb files or as a launcher among applications in order to install the deb by executing it with (double) click.

In Kubuntu with Dolphin I have created a service menu to create that context menu, also a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` to achieve the same action by executing the deb file.

The file `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/install-deb.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Actions=install
Icon=dialog-information
MimeType=application/vnd.debian.binary-package
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel


[Desktop Action install]
Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f
Icon=dialog-information
Name=Install
```

The file `~/.local/share/applications/install_deb_term.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Install in terminal with apt
Comment=Install deb files in terminal with apt
Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f
Icon=gdebi
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;System;
```

---

All is well, excepting the fact that without the `--hold` argument in `konsole` the terminal closes to quickly (which is not good in case of error), while with that argument the terminal stays open with a rather inconclusive message like so:

```
 Setting up <whatever_program> ...
```

which is not what I expect if the installation went fine.

---

***Can I get some "OK" message at the end of the installation process with `apt`? Maybe through a script containing the `apt` command?***

---

### Update:

Following comments by @DKBose: modifying `~/.bashrc` as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/748923/47206) answer I get the desired notification popup with a command in terminal like

`sudo apt install /path/to/deb; alert`

but **not** with the line

`Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f; alert`

in the files above (installation works, but no popup).

For the `alert` argument to work at all, installation of `libnotify-bin` was needed.

Comment: @DKBose - That one gives far less info. When missing dependencies it doesn't say which. Apt in terminal, like gdebi, shows a lot more info. I am trying to avoid gdebi in kde. A script should do it. I just need an ok message at the end, and even that just for the fun of it.

Comment: So, `apt install ... && echo OK`?

Comment: @DKBose - When missing dependencies cannot be installed (I just tested with an Exaile package in Kubuntu 18.04) they are not specified in `qapt-deb-installer`.

Comment: @muru - with the line `Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f && echo OK` I get no ok message in terminal (tested by successfully installing Opera: in that case the last line is `Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...`.) But maybe in a script.

Comment: And is https://askubuntu.com/questions/748860/how-can-i-use-the-eos-terminal-notification-in-ubuntu of help?

Comment: And this too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/749202/modify-the-alert-alias-in-bashrc

Comment: @DKBose - It was [exaile_3.4.5-1_all.deb](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/exaile/) (just testing, I don't want that, there are more recent versions anyway I guess), also I will try the askubuntu notification solution as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @DKBose - modifying `~/.bashrc` as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/748923/47206) answer I get the desired notification popup with a command in terminal like `sudo apt install /path/to/deb; alert`, but not with the line `Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f; alert` in the files above (installation works, but no popup). I will add that to question.

Comment: Please see if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention has something of use.

Comment: @DKBose - the answers under there are too complicated, for me, I do not know how to adjust those scripts to my use.. I learned that `echo $?` can be used at the end of a command, which gives `0` for ok. But it's the same as with `alert`: works when typed in terminal, but not with the terminal launched from the desktop file.

Comment: @DKBose OP's account seems to be deleted, maybe you can post an answer and remove this from the unanswered list?

Comment: @muru, that user is [cipricus](https://askubuntu.com/users/925128/cipricus) who has apparently moved to XFCE. The question here has two parts: one seems to be answered with the `alert` feature in `~/.bashrc` but the other aspect, involving the service menu route, is still very much open according to the [last comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100044/get-ok-message-when-installing-deb-with-apt-in-terminal-from-context-menu-or-cl?noredirect=1#comment1830938_1100044) by user47206. And I don't have an answer for that second aspect.

Comment: @DKBose that is probably just a syntax error. `Exec` lines aren't really parsed like shell lines, so the `; alert` probably should have been `konsole --hold -e bash -c 'apt install "$@";  alert' _ %f`.

Comment: @muru I tried `Exec=konsole --hold -e bash -c 'sudo apt install %f; alert' _ %f` with `sudo` added and with `%f` because KDE service menus use %f (obtained when a file is clicked in Dolphin). The installation is fine, but no alert, instead, the terminal shows `_: alert: command not found`.

Comment: @DKBose that's good, `alert` is an alias in bashrc, so changing `bash -c` to `bash -ic` should fix that

Comment: @muru Okay, with `Exec=konsole --hold -e bash -ic 'sudo apt install %f; alert' _ %f`, installation is fine, no alert, but now the last line is `No summary specified.`

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses the issue of installing a .deb file using `apt install` via a service menu in Kubuntu 18.04.

First, we download a small .deb, `gcolor2` which is not in the bionic repos, using the link provided by N0rbert [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073995/248158).

```
~/Downloads $ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcolor2/gcolor2_0.4-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Next, based on the service menu .desktop file in the question and comments by [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), the following service menu .desktop file, `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/install-deb.desktop` was constructed:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=install-deb
Icon=dialog-information
MimeType=application/vnd.debian.binary-package
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

[Desktop Action install-deb]
Name=install-deb
Exec=konsole --hold -e bash -ic 'sudo apt install %f && notify-send --expire-time=50000 "DONE"'
```

From now on, if one right-clicks on a .deb file in Dolphin, the context menu offers "install-deb" as one of the options. Selecting "install-deb" will open up `konsole` and run `sudo apt install %f`, where `%f` in this case, refers to the `gcolor` .deb downloaded via `wget`.

This is what konsole's output looks like:

```
[sudo] password for dkb: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcolor2' instead of '/home/dkb/Downloads/gcolor2_0.4-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcolor2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/25.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 112 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/dkb/Downloads/gcolor2_0.4-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb gcolor2 amd64 0.4-2.1ubuntu1 [25.4 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package gcolor2.
(Reading database ... 257481 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gcolor2_0.4-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcolor2 (0.4-2.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gcolor2 (0.4-2.1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
```

Once the install is complete, `konsole` will have "Finished" in its titlebar but will remain open until it is closed via the window manager. Additionally, because of the `notify-send` bit, a notification will be visible for the number of milliseconds specified. (I don't know why but `--urgency=critical` doesn't make the notification persist.)

---

`kdialog --passivepopup "whatever text string"` seems better suited for this purpose than `notify-send`.