# Wake me up when a [slow] command line process wants my attention?

Tags: bash, monitoring

Sometimes I use command line programs, that want input after a rather long time, and it helps getting their jobs done, if there is an alert, an audio message and/or an info window on top of the current windows on the desktop. I am thinking of a graphical desktop environment or window manager. A special version might be made for Ubuntu Server that works in text mode unless the GUI tool works via a terminal window and via `ssh`.

If I made my own program or if it is a small shellscript, I can modify it to produce the alert, but many programs are supplied without source code, or it is rather difficult to mess with it. So it would be nice to have a tool in the Ubuntu system, that can monitor most compiled programs as well as scripts and wake me up when a [slow] command line process wants my attention.

- When something is written, it indicates that a program is waiting for input or has finished and the result is ready for me to use.
- So how can I find or make a tool that monitors the activity in a terminal window and produces an alert, when something is written?

Comment: Is that up to the developers to implement this?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, I don't think this needs advanced programming skills. I am trying to do something with bash shellscripts. Maybe other people here have better solutions. Maybe there are already good solutions ...

Comment: Maybe [`expect`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/when_to_use_expect_scripting_and_when_to_avoid_it10) would be useful? I've never used it myself.

Comment: @wjandrea, I have had a short glance at `expect`. Yes, maybe it can be useful.

Comment: Relevant, but seems not quite a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete

Comment: See also [Send a notification or alert when bash asks for input from user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491121/send-a-notification-or-alert-when-bash-asks-for-input-from-user/491248#491248)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Monitoring the dialogue of a program and send an alert

You can monitor the activity of

1. a **[fifo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))** using the shellscript **`viafifo`** or
2. an **`xterm` log file** using the shellscript **`vialog`**

and let it start a **`zenity` info message**, when there is input from the monitored program. If you wish, you can also install **`espeak`** and let it send an **audio message**.

#### 1. Start a `zenity` info message, when there is input from a monitored program using a fifo using `viafifo`.

The following shellscript can monitor the output dialogue from a program and send an alert. It needs `espeak` and `script` (and `script` need not be installed in Ubuntu).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install espeak
```

- assuming a graphical desktop environment
- start a shellscript in a terminal window, let us call it **`viafifo`**.
- starting the program to be monitored 'in `viafifo`'
- **running the dialogue in the terminal window** (that is where you write your input)
- using a fifo to get access to the output of the program to be monitored, `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `dev/stderr`. The main task in the shellscript is the line with the program **`script`**, that is monitoring the activity in the terminal window and writing to the fifo.
- running a `while` loop

  - testing if the fifo has been modified and in that case

    - starting a `zenity` info message window and a correspoding spoken message with `espeak`.
    - short delays are allowed during typing the input (8 seconds; you can edit the script file to change the delay time).

You are expected to close the `zenity` window (can work with 'Enter') to get back to the `xterm` window, where you write your input.

Type `exit` to leave `script` and `viafifo`. After that you can get a log file with the whole dialogue.

```
#!/bin/bash

# date        editor   comment
# 2019-01-01  sudodus  version 1.0
# 2019-01-05  sudodus  fixed output of version
# 2019-01-05  sudodus  version 1.1

version=1.1

name=${0##*/}

# Usage

if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]
then
 echo "'$name' is a wrapper, that sends a notification, when the wrapped program
has written to standard input and standard error and may be waiting for input.
---
Usage:   $name <options>
Example: $name
         $name -h       # this help text
         $name -v       # show version"
 exit
elif [ "$1" == "-v" ]
then
 echo "$name version $version"
 exit
fi

# Preparation

message="Check, if the monitored program asks for input"

inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
tmpfifo=$(mktemp --tmpdir=$tmpdir)
rm "$tmpfifo"
mkfifo "$tmpfifo"
#ls -l "$tmpdir"
sleep 1
cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$tmpfifo")

< "$tmpfifo" cat >> $tmpdir/${name}.log  &

# Monitor the output from program with a while loop

while true
do
  if test -f $tmpdir/stop
  then
   break
  fi
  cnt0=$cnt1
  sleep 0.5
  cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$tmpfifo")

  if [ $cnt1 -gt $((cnt0+8)) ]
  then
#   zenity --notification --text="$message" 2> /dev/null
   espeak "$message" &
   zenity --info --title="${0##*/} ${1##*/} $2 ..." \
    --text="$message" --width=500  2> /dev/null
   sleep 0.5
   cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$tmpfifo")
  fi
  sleep 1
done &

# Prepare for the monitoring

echo -en "\0033]0;$name: 'exit' to leave subshell\0007"
echo -en "\0033]1;$name\0007"
ncol=$(tput cols)
nfill=$((ncol -13 -${#name}))
hyphs=$(for ((i=1;i<=nfill;i++));do echo -n '-';done;echo '')
echo -e "$inversvid----- Start $name $hyphs$resetvid"
tstart=$(date '+%s')

# Monitoring

script -fq $tmpfifo

# Finish writing after monitoring

tend=$(date '+%s')
tuse=$((tend-tstart))
winttl=$(pwd)
echo -en "\0033]0;$winttl\0007"
echo -en "\0033]1;$winttl\0007"
ncol=$(tput cols)
nfill=$((ncol -11 -${#name}))
hyphs=$(for ((i=1;i<=nfill;i++));do echo -n '-';done;echo '')
echo -e "$inversvid----- End $name $hyphs$resetvid"

touch $tmpdir/stop  # to break the while loop
sleep 3

savlog="Finished. Save the log '${name}.log'?"

espeak "$savlog" &
zenity --question --title="${0##*/} ${1##*/} $2 ..." \
    --text="$savlog" --width=500  2> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
 echo "$name used $tuse seconds" >> $tmpdir/${name}.log
 mv $tmpdir/${name}.log . && echo "See '${name}.log'" || echo "Failed to save the log file"
fi
echo "$name used $tuse seconds plus a few (5-10) seconds for preparing and finishing"

# Clean up

rm -r "$tmpdir"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### 2. Start a `zenity` info message, when something is written to an `xterm` window (from the monitored program or from the user) using `vialog`.

The following shellscript can monitor the dialogue with a program and send an alert. It needs `espeak` and `xterm`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install espeak xterm
```

- assuming a graphical desktop environment
- start a shellscript in a terminal window, which is used like a 'console' for **`vialog`**
- starting the program to be monitored in an `xterm` window
- **running the dialogue in the `xterm` window** (that is where you write your input)
- using a log file of `xterm` to get access to the output from and input to the program to be monitored
- running a `while` loop

  - testing if the log file has been modified and in that case

    - starting a `zenity` info message window and a correspondig spoken message with `espeak`.
    - short delays are allowed during typing the input (8 seconds; you can edit the script file to change the delay time).

You are expected to close the `zenity` window (can work with 'Enter') to get back to the `xterm` window, where you write your input.

Close the `xterm` window to stop monitoring.

```
#!/bin/bash

# date        editor   comment
# 2018-12-31  sudodus  version 1.0

version=1.0

name="${0##*/}"
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]
then
 echo "'$name' is a wrapper, that sends a notification, when the wrapped program
has written to standard input and standard error and may be waiting for input.
---
Usage:    $name [program name] [parameters]
Examples: $name          # to run program(s) interactively in an xterm window
          $name program
          $name -h       # to get help (this text)
          $name -v       # show version"
 exit
elif [ "$1" == "-v" ]
then
 echo "$name version $version"
 exit
fi
tstart=$(date '+%s')
echo "----- start $name at $(date '+%F %T') ----------------------------"
tmpstr="${1##*/}"
xtermlog=$(mktemp -u)

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
 mess_zenity="Check, if the monitored program asks for input"
 mess_espeak="${mess_zenity/program/, Program,}"
 xterm -title "monitored by ${0##*/}" -fa default -fs 11 -bg '#2c2b2a' \
 -l -lf "$xtermlog" -sb -rightbar 2> /dev/null & pid=$!
else
 mess_espeak="Check if '${tmpstr^} ${2##*/} ${3##*/} ...' asks for input"
 mess_zenity="Check if '$tmpstr $2 $3 ...' asks for input"
 xterm -title "${1##*/} $2 $3 ..." -fa default -fs 11 -bg '#2c2b2a' \
 -l -lf "$xtermlog" -e "$@" 2> /dev/null & pid=$!
fi
sleep 0.5
sync
cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$xtermlog")
tail -f "$xtermlog" & ptail=$!

cont=true
while $cont
do
 sleep 1
 cnt0=$cnt1
 tmpstr=$(ps -Af |sed "s/grep $pid//"|grep "$pid")
# echo "$tmpstr"
 if [ "$tmpstr" != "" ]
 then
  cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$xtermlog")
  if [ $cnt1 -gt $((cnt0 + 8)) ]
  then
#   zenity --notification --text="$message" 2> /dev/null
   espeak "$mess_espeak" &
   zenity --info --title="${0##*/} ${1##*/} $2 ..." \
    --text="$mess_zenity" --width=500  2> /dev/null
   touch "$xtermlog"
   cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$xtermlog")
  fi
  sleep 1
  else
  sleep .2
  # echo "process $pid has finished"
  cont=false
 fi
done

# clean up
tmpstr="$(tail -n1 "$xtermlog" | sed 's/.*exit.*/exit/')"
if [ "$tmpstr" != "exit" ]
then
 echo ""
fi
rm -r "$xtermlog"
kill $ptail
tend=$(date '+%s')
tuse=$((tend-tstart))
echo "------- end $name at $(date '+%F %T') --- used $tuse seconds"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### 3. Ubuntu Server monitored remotely via `ssh`

> A special version might be made for Ubuntu Server that works in text mode
>   unless the GUI tool works via a terminal window and via ssh.

I checked, and these tools work with a server via a text mode connection via `ssh` to a computer with a graphical desktop environment.

- The following screenshot illustrates how `vialog` is started in the client (a laptop with Ubuntu persistent live).
- Then `ssh` connects to the server and performs some time-consuming task (here illustrated by copying a couple of big iso files.
- It takes enough time to copy the Ubuntu Studio iso file for the alert to be activated, when the command wants a decision from me in the middle of the process (overwrite or not).

[image]